# Assign event in plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I was developed a plugin that for assign contextmenu.
Html Code:

```
<ul id='list1'>
 <li class='item'>Items</li>
 <li class='item'>Items</li>
 <li class='item'>Items</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

jQuery plugin code:

```
$(function(){
 $.fn.cnxtmenu=function(options){
   this.bind('contextmenu',function(){
    //To display menu
    });
  }
});
```

Usage of plugin:

```
$('#list1').cnxtmenu(options);
$('.item').cnxtmenu(options);
```

My problem is plugin code is executing many times.

Comment: How do you trigger the `contextmenu` event?

Comment: Can you show the code where you do that?

Comment: @davids I am very new to plugin development this.bind is to adding contextmenu listener to the elements

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is, as you are attaching the handler to several elements and to their container as well, the event is bubbling up and the handler is executed twice. So, in your `bind`, try this:

```
// Remember to pass 'ev' to the handler
this.bind('contextmenu',function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    //To display menu
});
```

As I told you, is my first guess. I'd need the code where you trigger the `contextmenu` event to give a more accurate answer. If your code is executing, somewhere you must have `$(something).trigger('contextmenu')`